# Using Ajax how can I match a input value from a form to records in my database and fetch associated record/row to prefill a form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, mysqli

I have a form input named "invoiceidcopy" ...I need to match the value of a this input value to that of the value in my database under the column (invoiceidcopy) and then fetch associated record/row of form data to prefill my form when the "#submit-id" button is clicked.  My form and data base have the following inputs/columns named "invoiceidcopy", "location", "q1", "subcheck".  Below is as far as I've gotten I feel like I'm close if even that.  I can't figure out what I'm missing or how to make this code work.  Much appreciation and Thanks to anyone's help in advance.

**FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#">

<input id="invoiceidcopy" name="invoiceidcopy" type="text" value="XXXIDXXX"/>



         <button id="submit-id">Prefill Form</button>


        <input id="location" name="location" required="" type="text">



<input type="radio" id="q1" name="q1" value="4.99" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" id="q1" name="q1" value="7.99" />

        <input id="subcheck" name="subcheck" value="0" type="hidden">
        <input id="subcheck" name="subcheck" value="1" onclick="return false" checked="" type="checkbox">Agree to Terms of Service


    <button id="btn1" type="submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>




<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
     $(function(){


        $('#submit-id').on('click', function(e){  // Things to do when '#submit-id' button is clicked
            var invoiceidcopy = $('#invoiceidcopy').val(); // Grab user invoiceidcopy from text field
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submit, we are submiting form down with ajax.

             $.ajax({
              url: "/tst/orders2.php",
              data: {


invoiceidcopy:invoiceidcopy  


               }
            }).done(function(data) {
data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#location').val(data.location);
$('#q1').val(data.q1);
$('#subcheck').val(data.subcheck);
});
        });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/tst/orders2.php**

```
<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}



  if (isset($_GET['invoiceidcopy']))
{
    $invoiceidcopy= $_GET['invoiceidcopy'];

   $query = "SELECT location, q1, subcheck
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE invoiceidcopy = '".($invoiceidcopy)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo json_encode($row);
 die(); 
} 


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an invalid form action. Should be "/" at least.

After that I would check the server logs to see if there's something failing somewhere. Have you verified that query works directly on the database?

Comment: yeah its just a placeholder

Comment: i've been going over and over this code forever and I cant figure out what Im missing...

Comment: Like I said, check your server logs to see if there's an error. If not, check that the query actually returns anything by using the mysql console. What exactly *are* you seeing?

Comment: when i click the button nothing happens...the console shows its returning values...but not values get prefilled in the form inputs...thanks for your time

Comment: Well, you aren't doing anything but echoing the json_encode'd version onto the page. I see no code related to populating form fields.

Comment: How can i populate the form fields

Comment: Thanks for ur help man...could you tell me how and where do i need to put this code for me to achieve what im trying to do...thanks for ur help and effort

Comment: You will either need to return the form's html with the fields populated already, or you could use javascript and AJAX to request the data(looks like you are already JSON-encoding it) and then use jquery or something to populate the fields in the browser. To do it the first way you should look into having a lookup script separate from the form submission script.